# C++ Resource file ProductVersion showing variable names instead of variable values

Tags: c++, resources, version

I'm trying to set up my program's versioning, so I can increment it with each build, but I'm having some trouble setting up the version for the `.exe`.

Here's my `BuildVersion.h`

```
#define STRINGIZE(s) #s

#define VER_MAJOR_VERSION   6
#define VER_MINOR_VERSION   7
#define VER_HOTFIX_VERSION  0
#define VER_BUILD_NUMBER    999

#define VER_FILE_VERSION    VER_MAJOR_VERSION, VER_MINOR_VERSION, VER_HOTFIX_VERSION, VER_BUILD_NUMBER
#define VER_FILE_VERSION_STR    STRINGIZE(VER_MAJOR_VERSION)    \
"." STRINGIZE(VER_MINOR_VERSION)    \
"." STRINGIZE(VER_HOTFIX_VERSION)   \
"." STRINGIZE(VER_BUILD_NUMBER) \

#define VER_PRODUCT_VERSION         VER_FILE_VERSION
#define VER_PRODUCT_VERSION_STR     VER_FILE_VERSION_STR
```

And here's the version section of my `.rc` file

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Version
//

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION VER_FILE_VERSION
 PRODUCTVERSION VER_PRODUCT_VERSION
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x0L
 FILETYPE 0x1L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "My Company"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "My Description"
            VALUE "FileVersion", VER_FILE_VERSION_STR "\0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "MyProgram.exe"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "© 2019 My copyright"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "MyProgram.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "My Program"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", VER_PRODUCT_VERSION_STR "\0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    END
END
```

But here's what it shows in my `.exe` Properties

[image: Properties]

As you can see, the Product version shows `VER_MAJOR_VERSION.VER_MINOR_VERSION.VER_HOTFIX_VERSION.VER_BUILD_NUMBER`, instead of the expected integers like the File version.  It's using the variable names instead of the variable values.

I've tried just setting `PRODUCTVERSION` and `"ProductVersion"` to use `VER_FILE_VERSION` and `VER_FILE_VERSION_STR`, respectively, instead of their own separate `PRODUCT_VERSION` variables, but the same thing happens.

Using Visual Studio 2017, Windows SDK 10.0.15063.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not stringify'ing the *values* of the macros, you are stringify'ing the *names* of the macros.  You need an extra level of processing in order to evaluate the macros before you then stringify their results, eg:

```
#define STRINGIZE_(s) #s
#define STRINGIZE(s) STRINGIZE_(s)
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks, that fixed it!